# What effect does using LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext have with async / await code in .net 4.7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, async-await, .net-4.7

I'm upgrading a legacy Asp.Net WebForms project to .net 4.7.

In my configuration I set the target framework to 4.7 and synchronization context to use the new `AspNetSynchronizationContext` (although I believe the latter is implied if omitted) to allow new `async / await` methods to work e.g.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" />
...
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

But then I found *lots* of code along the lines of the following:

```
var myTask = DoSomethingAsync();
return myTask.Result;
```

The result of the task is not being awaited which causes the app to hang.

If I change my configuration to use the `LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext` ...

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
```

... the legacy non-awaited code works again and the new `async/await` methods ***appear*** to work. I say "appear" as I read in [this MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/) that:

> the behavior of async / await is undefined in ASP.NET unless this switch has been set

Why is it undefined? Does this mean the behaviour is unpredictable or just won't work?

If I have a snippet of code like the following what will or could happen when it is called in a `LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext`?

```
public async Task<bool> DoSomethingElseAsync()
{
    return await CallSomeApiAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: "Undefined" means "has not been defined". The ASP.NET team have not formally defined what the system **should** do, so you can't have any expectation to what your code will do. It might work fine, it might do nothing, it might cause your sever to sell itself on eBay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext` means you don't get a defined behaviour when using tasks; the legacy synchronization model was not built to work with task-scheduling. You *must* use the new synchronization context if you want to use tasks inside ASP.NET.

```
var myTask = DoSomethingAsync();
return myTask.Result;
```

This code blocks on a `Task`. Calling `Wait()` or `Result` on a running `Task` will block the calling thread until the `Task` completes.

You can't safely block on tasks unless you know:

- The task has already completed (in which case you're not really blocking).
- The synchronization context will not attempt to resume on the same thread the task started on.

The only reasonable solution is **to use tasks all the way down**. Any methods which attempt to block on a `Task` should instead be changed to return a `Task` or `Task<TResult>` and `await` the running `Task` instead.

Comment: Thanks @paul. I was hoping that with the volume of legacy code involved that there might be an alternate to `async` all the way.